# Show that $\exists \mu(y/x)$ integration factor for $P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the equation:

$$
P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = 0
$$

Has an intergraion factor of the form:
$$
\mu = (\frac{y}{x})
$$

If and only if the term $x^2\frac{P_y-Q_x}{xP+yQ}$ depends only on the term $\frac{y}{x}$.

---

So in order to have an intergration factor i think we should bring the equation to a linear form, namely:

$$
y’ + p(x)y = g(x)
$$

Therefore we can write our equation as:
$$
y’ + \frac{Q}{P} = 0
$$

That is the closest i got to the linear equation i want to get to, but its not exactly.

Am i looking on the question the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: Multiply the $1$-form $Pdx+Qdy$ by $\mu$, then apply Cartan's exterior differential operator $d$ to it, which is in this case the curl. Then $\mu$ is an integrating factor iff the curl of $\mu (Pdx+Qdy)$ vanishes. This is how I would start it, and then see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

I will prove one direction only (though I think it shouldn't be too hard to prove the other direction, given my solution).

Assume $\mu = \mu(y/x)$ is an integrating factor. Then

$$ d(\mu(Pdx+Qdy)) = 0, $$

where $d$ is Cartan's exterior differential (which is basically the curl in this case). We then get

$$ \frac{\mu'}{x^2}(xdy-ydx) \wedge (Pdx+Qdy) + \mu(Q_x - P_y) dx \wedge dy = 0.$$

Hence

$$-\frac{\mu'}{x^2}(xP+yQ) + \mu(Q_x - P_y) = 0.$$

Therefore

$$\frac{\mu'}{\mu} = -x^2\left(\frac{P_y-Q_x}{xP+yQ}\right).$$

This shows that the right-hand side of the previous formula depends only on $y/x$.

Edit: $\mu$ is an integrating factor iff $\mu P dx + \mu Q dy$ is exact iff:

$$(\mu P)_y - (\mu Q)_x = 0.$$

This fact can be found in many books on ODEs I presume. I am referring to the fact that $f(x,y) dx + g(x,y) dy$ is exact iff $f_y - g_x = 0$, assuming $f$ and $g$ are smooth (of course the assumptions can be weakened).

Note that $\mu = \mu(y/x)$, so that

$\mu_y = \mu'(y/x) 1/x$,

by the chain rule and that

$\mu_x = -\mu'(y/x) y/x^2$,

also by the chain rule. By the way $y/x$ is here the argument of $\mu'$, since $\mu$ itself is a function of $y/x$. It is *not* $\mu'$ times $y/x$ (just to clarify).

Therefore $\mu$ is an integrating factor iff

$$ \mu_y P + \mu P_y - \mu_x Q - \mu Q_x = 0 $$

iff

$$ \frac{P \mu'}{x} + \mu P_y + \frac{\mu' y Q}{x^2} - \mu Q_x = 0. $$

Hence

$$\frac{\mu'}{x^2}(xP+yQ) - \mu(Q_x - P_y) = 0.$$

Therefore

$$\frac{\mu'}{\mu} = -x^2\left(\frac{P_y-Q_x}{xP+yQ}\right).$$

This shows that the right-hand side of the previous formula depends only on $y/x$ (since the left-hand side only depends on $y/x$). I hope this edit is easier to follow than my previous answer. There remains to prove the converse, which I think should be doable now, using my solution of half the problem. Let me know if this is now readable.

Comment: Thank you but I don’t understand what you did, and why did you use $\cap$ What is the meaning in an equation?

Comment: @Alon, is it better now? If you want, just read the part starting from Edit. I tried to make it more readable (sorry I didn't do that earlier, I was quite busy).